# How to create a temporary file with Unicode encoding?

Tags: python, unicode, temporary-files

When I use `open()` to open a file, I am not able to write unicode strings. I have learned that I need to use `codecs` and open the file with Unicode encoding (see http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data).

Now I need to create some temporary files. I tried to use the `tempfile` library, but it doesn't have any encoding option. When I try to write any unicode string in a temporary file with `tempfile`, it fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tempfile
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fh:
  fh.write(u"Hello World: ä")
  fh.seek(0)
  for line in fh:
    print line
```

How can I create a temporary file with Unicode encoding in Python?

Edit:

1. I am using Linux and the error message that I get for this code is:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "tmp_file.py", line 5, in <module>
       fh.write(u"Hello World: ä")
   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
   ```
2. This is just an example. In practice I am trying to write a string that some API returned.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Everyone else's answers are correct, I just want to clarify what's going on:

The difference between the literal `'foo'` and the literal `u'foo'` is that the former is a string of bytes and the latter is the Unicode object.

First, understand that Unicode is the character set. UTF-8 is the encoding. The Unicode object is the about the former—it's a Unicode string, not necessarily a UTF-8 one. In your case, the encoding for a string literal will be UTF-8, because you specified it in the first lines of the file.

To get a Unicode string from a byte string, you call the `.encode()` method:

```
>>>> u"ひらがな".encode("utf-8") == "ひらがな"
True
```

Similarly, you could call your string.encode in the `write` call and achieve the same effect as just removing the `u`.

If you didn't specify the encoding in the top, say if you were reading the Unicode data from another file, you would specify what encoding it was in before it reached a Python string.  This would determine how it would be represented in bytes (i.e., the `str` type).

The error you're getting, then, is only because the `tempfile` module is expecting a `str` object.  This ***doesn't*** mean it can't handle unicode, just that it expects you to pass in a byte string rather than a Unicode object—because without you specifying an encoding, it wouldn't know how to write it to the temp file.

Comment: Yes. So, there's no need to open tempfile with some magic unicode option, it's enough to write an explicitly encoded string: `fh.write(u'föo bār'.encode('utf-8'))`. Replace 'utf-8' with 'utf-16' if most of your characters are CJKs.

Comment: @9000: beware of this method if you use 'utf-16'. If doing so you will have to write the whole file at once, because encode('utf-16') also output the file BOM. If you have several strings to write to the same file, the first one should be with .encode('utf-16') and the subsequent ones with .encode('utf-16-le') wich does not send the BOM. Using some magic unicode option avoid this pitfall.

Comment: `"abc"` is a Unicode string in Python 3 or in the presence of `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.

Answer (score 17):

tempfile.TemporaryFile has [encoding option in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tempfile
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
  fh.write("Hello World: ä")
  fh.seek(0)
  for line in fh:
    print(line)
```

Note that now you need to specify mode='w+' instead of the default binary mode. Also note that string literals are implicitly Unicode in Python 3, there's no *u* modifier.

If you're stuck with [Python 2.6, temporary files](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) are always binary, and you need to encode the Unicode string before writing it to the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tempfile
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fh:
  fh.write(u"Hello World: ä".encode('utf-8'))
  fh.seek(0)
  for line in fh:
    print line.decode('utf-8')
```

Unicode specifies the character set, not the encoding, so in either case you need a way to specify how to encode the Unicode characters!

Comment: That's a good idea to also decode the 8-bit string that's being read from the file (in the Python 2 example), converting it into a Unicode string, before printing. (Fixed it.)

Answer (score 7):

Since I am working on a Python program with TemporaryFile objects that should run in both Python 2 and Python 3, I don't find it satisfactory to manually encode all strings written as UTF-8 like the other answers suggest.

Instead, I have written the following small polyfill (because I could not find something like it in six) to wrap a binary file-like object into a UTF-8 file-like object:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
import codecs
if sys.hexversion < 0x03000000:
    def uwriter(fp):
        return codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(fp)
else:
    def uwriter(fp):
        return fp
```

It is used in the following way:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
with uwriter(NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.txt', mode='w')) as fp:
    fp.write('Hællo wörld!\n')
```

Answer (score 5):

I have figured out one solution: create a temporary file that is not automatically deleted with `tempfile`, close it and open it again using `codecs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs
import os
import tempfile

f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
filename = f.name
f.close()

with codecs.open(filename, 'w+b', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
  fh.write(u"Hello World: ä")
  fh.seek(0)
  for line in fh:
    print line

os.unlink(filename)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is suboptimal. See @spinning_plate's answer and my comment to it; things are _way_ simpler.

Comment: @9000 I don't see an answer of `spinning_plate` here.

Comment: @guettli: must be a some kind of typo; I must have meant the answer of `dfb`, currently the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write a unicode object `(u"...")` to the temporary file where you should use an encoded string `("...")`.  You don't have to explicitly pass an `"encode="` parameter, because you've already stated the encoding in line two `("# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-")`.  Just use `fh.write("ä")` instead of `fh.write(u"ä")` and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, this works, but I am actually trying to write a string that some API returned, so there is no `(u"...")` in my code. I have updated my question with this information. 
I tried an example with two files, and `fh.write(other_file.f())` works or not depending on the other file having the encoding or not. In my real code I don't have any control of the code that is creating the string.

Answer (score -1):

Dropping the u made your code work for me:

```
fh.write("Hello World: ä")
```

I guess it's because it's already unicode.

Comment: Yes, running the script on a linux box, without the u, produces the correct output `Hello World: ä`

Comment: Yes, this works... 
Actually in my real program I am getting the input from some API, and it fails, so it was not because of "the u" in my code.

Comment: @john: Dropping the u is probably not doing what you believe even if you get the right utf-8 in the final file. It is likely that you used some utf-8 editor if so when typing 'ä' two bytes are stored in the string. This is easy enough to check. If so len("Hello World: ä") will be 15 and "Hello World: ä"[14] will be '\xa4'.

Answer (score -1):

Setting the sys as default encoding to UTF-8 will fix the encoding issue

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') #set to utf-8 by default this will solve the errors

import tempfile
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fh:
  fh.write(u"Hello World: ä")
  fh.seek(0)
  for line in fh:
    print line
```